# How to indent with "python -c" on the command line

Tags: python, python-3.x

On the command line,

`python -c "z = [i for i in range(5)]; print (z)"`  gives

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

where `;` means there should be a newline.

But what about a newline followed by a tab? Or (gasp) two tabs?

The following code is nonfunctional, but it illustrates what I'd like to be able to do:

`python -c "z = [i for i in range(5)]; for i in z: print (i)"`

and get as output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

So basically the question is: How do I execute the following code using `python -c`?

```
z = [i for i in range(5)] 
for i in z:
    print (i)
```

Comment: If you use all in a string, you might use "\n" as a new line and add the correct number of spaces.

Comment: Please clarify your question. A multi-line program is a perfectly valid input for ``python -c``. Do you know how to write multi-line strings in your shell?

Comment: @pfabri yes the answer by SilentGhost worked, but not the accepted answer, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `;` is *not* always a valid substitute for a newline, so the question is really: how do I supply arbitrary code. This basically depends on knowing how to use your shell.

In `bash`, you can construct true one-liners using `$'...'` quoting:

```
python -c $'z = [i for i in range(5)]\nfor i in z:\n    print(i)'
```

though it is easier to read if you can embed newlines yourself:

```
python -c '
z = [i for i in range(5)]
for i in z:
    print(i)
'
```

Note that since indentation is so significant, you can't easily do this if the call to `python` *itself* is indented in a shell script, as your script indentation would be part of the argument itself.

```
if [[ cmd = "do it" ]]; then

    # The Python script has to be dedented
    python -c '
z = [i for i in range(5)]
for i in z:
    print(i)
'
fi
```